# How to use If and Indirect combination in excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have two dependent drop down boxes. I used INDIRECT function to get the second drop down filled. Now the query is, there are some blank spaces in the contents of the second drop down and I want to remove those. So thought of using If and Indirect functions at a time. Is it possible to use both at a time. If so please specify.

The data validation for second drop down box is `=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))`

Column 1 //for dropdown 1

```
    a
    ab
    abc
    abcd
    abcde
    abcdf
```

When I select 'ab' in column1 then it displays  the following

Column 2 //for drop down 2

```
    ab
    1
    2

    4
    5

    7
```

the above 1,2,4,5,7 will be in drop down list with spaces as shown above.

I have used `=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))` for second drop down. now I want to check for emptyness of the cell and I don't want to display the blank cell ie I want to display only

`1 2 4 5 7` in a drop down

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you show a bit of your code, please?

Comment: @EngJon added the details.

Comment: This is not really vba related. However, you can achieve this in vba (by creating a new range, only containing non empty cells from the original range and defining the source of the dropdown box as the new range)

Comment: Where is your data for dropdown2 coming from? The short answer is - you will need to sort the data in column 2 to remove the blanks. If that's not possible from your source data, then you can create an intermediary column which creates a sorted list of your unsorted data, and then have your indirect function refer to that. Also - what is in cell A1?

Answer (score 0):

If you use "Data Validation" drop-down list, there are some limits: it can use a link to a range, or list of items (a string), or formula that returns range (like OFFSET, INDEX etc.), but not array of values.
For removing blanks from the list you can use a formula that returns an array of values, but it cannot be used in Data Validation dropdown.
So, if it is impossible to sort or remove blank cells from your list, then yppu should look to VBA, where you can generate a list for dropdown as a string:

```
TargetRange.Validation.Delete
TargetRange.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=Join(Arr, ",")
```

where *Arr* is an array of values for your dropdown, and *Arr* generated by event on first dropdown change (you can use Worksheet_Change event).